# SwiftMailer page isn't working

Tags: php, logging, swiftmailer

I'm trying to get SwiftMailer working in my application, but so far have made zero progress beyond simply installing it via Composer and adding the include for the autoloader.

Here is my code:

```
require_once "./swiftmailer/vendor/autoload.php";

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance(
    Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('....net', 25)
        ->setUserName('...@....org')
        ->setPassword('...')
);

$logger = new Swift_Plugins_Loggers_EchoLogger();
$mailer->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_Loggers_EchoLogger($logger));

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Test message')
    ->setFrom(array("i...@....org"))
    ->setTo(array("m...@...org"))
    ->setBody("This is a test message");

$num = $mailer->send($message);

printf("Sent %d messages\n", $num);

echo $logger->dump();
```

The only response I'm getting from the server is "The  page isn't working".  I've tried commenting out various blocks in the code to see if I can identify where the problem is.  Before I added the logger plugin, it happened when on executing the $mailer->sendMessage() line.  After attempting to add the logger plugin, it happens when I initialize the login with the $logger = new Swift.... line.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: anything from http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php ?

Comment: I added error_reporting(E_ALL) immediately before initializing my $mailer instance, but still get the same result, or lack thereof.